# Parsing date and time from file name and path

Tags: regex, bash

How do I parse date and time from file path and name using regular expression?

I have files stored in a folder like this

```
/home/user/folder/sub/2017-20-10/001/jpg/14/48/31[M][0@0][0].jpg
```

Basically this tells me that the image is taken from camera `001` on `2017-20-10 14:48:31`

I would like to copy this file to a new location with a name as the date and time parsed from the path + name so new file would be i.e. `20172010144831.jpg`

What would be the best way to do this? I would presume regular expression. What would this expression look like?

Comment: What is the regexp that you have tried?

Comment: I got nothing. I can't figure out how to split with / and get n'th part

Comment: `YYYY-DD-MM` is an odd format for a date.

Comment: is it `31[xyz].jpg` actual basename? Does the basename of each file contain seconds value?

Comment: Actual file is 03[M][0@0][0].jpg. Will edit to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you wouldn't have to duplicate the regular expression and the pattern for the iteration, but this is at least straightforward and easy to understand.

```
regex=/home/user/folder/sub/(....-..-..)/(.*)/jpg/(..)/(..)/(..).*\.jpg
for f in /home/user/folder/sub/*/*/jpg/*/*/*.jpg; do
  # Match against the regex, or skip to the next file
  [[ $f =~ $regex ]] || continue
  # The first capture group is the date. Strip the -.
  d=${BASH_REMATCH[1]//-}
  # The next three capture groups are the hour, minute, and second
  t=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:2:3}")
  printf -v new_name '%s%s%s%s.jpg' "$d" "${t[@]}" # Put them all together
done
```

Comment: I must note that this would also match non-datetime paths like `/home/user/folder/sub/aaaa-a1-11/dd/jpg/01/a2/f3`

Comment: As you should. I was too lazy to replace the appropriate `.`s with `[[:digit:]]` the last time I updated the answer. Even that is too permissive, though, as it would allows invalid dates like `2017-99-99`. I leave the task of writing a properly restrictive regular expression, or adding additional tests on `d` and `t` to the body of the loop, as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution with specific regex pattern:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep \
-regex  ".*/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/[0-9]+/jpg/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}.*.jpg$" \
-exec bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; 
      pat="/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/[0-9]+/jpg/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})"; 
      [[ "$0" =~ $pat ]]; items="${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:6}"; 
      cp "$0" "dest_dir/${items// /}.jpg"' {} \;
```

---

- `dest_dir` - is your *new location*